# Why make cannot pick up environment variables

Tags: c++, linux, shell, makefile

I have tested a few makes and having issues of environment variables in the shell is not inside the Make file. I wonder what is wrong in my setup.  I tested on my mac os, redhat, and Ubuntu.  They all have the same behavior.  I wonder anyone can help with this.

```
GNU Make 4.1
```

Here is my simplest make file:

```
ifdef $(HOME)
 $(info $$HOME is $(HOME))
else
 $(info $$HOME is undefined)
endif

all :
    echo do nothing
```

When typing make at the terminal I get

```
$HOME is undefined
echo do nothing
do nothing
```

echo $HOME

```
/Users/myusername
```

Here is the definition from make's manual book https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html

Variables in make can come from the environment in which make is run. Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value. But an explicit assignment in the makefile, or with a command argument, overrides the environment.

Comment: Actually I was testing another environment variable that I defined in my $HOME/.bash_profile.  I forget to do the export.  The variable is visible if I do echo $MYVARABLE but not inside the make. I made another mistake here in testing the environment variable in my dummy make file by givint the extra '$'.  Thanks for Dan's answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you linked to the make 3.79.1 docs here? Especially since the link is an `old-gnu` URL and you are specifically using a **much** newer version of make than that? (Fourteen and a half years newer to be exact.)

Comment: No particular reason. I just did a search on google and that's the first item from the google search.  It must be that most users of make are experts, and they don't read the newer manual any more. So the older version get the most publicity.

Comment: Perhaps because I've searched for it before but I get the toplevel GNU make page and have never seen Google return anything on that site before. <shrug>

Answer (score 3):

I believe you shouldn't get the value of your HOME variable in the ifdef block. GNU make will evaluate it to

```
ifdef /your/home/directory
```

which is obviously not defined as a variable. Try the following:

```
ifdef HOME
    $(info $$HOME is $(HOME))
else        
    $(info $$HOME is undefined)
endif
```

Comment: Correct, the syntax is `ifdef VAR_NAME` not `ifdef VAR_VALUE`. See [Syntax of Conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax) in the manual for more details.